# Is it possible to unbind specific event handlers in jQuery when 2 or more are the same?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at this code:

```
$(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {
    console.log('hello');
});

$(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {
    console.log('goodbye');
});
```

If at some point I want to prevent "hello" from being console logged but still want "goodbye" to be logged how to do that?

Because this:

```
$(window).unbind('load resize scroll');
```

Cancels both logs.

Comment: use event namespace http://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/

Comment: Read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [event namespaces](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names)

> An event name can be qualified by event namespaces that simplify
>   removing or triggering the event. For example, "click.myPlugin.simple"
>   defines both the myPlugin and simple namespaces for this particular
>   click event. A click event handler attached via that string could be
>   removed with .off("click.myPlugin") or .off("click.simple") without
>   disturbing other click handlers attached to the elements. Namespaces
>   are similar to CSS classes in that they are not hierarchical; only one
>   name needs to match. Namespaces beginning with an underscore are
>   reserved for jQuery's use.

```
$(window).on('load.one resize.one scroll.one', function() {
    console.log('hello');
});

$(window).on('load.two resize.two scroll.two', function() {
    console.log('goodbye');
});
```

then

```
$(window).off('load.one resize.one scroll.one');
```

Answer (score 3):

Name your handlers:

```
function sayHello() {
    console.log('hello');
}

function sayGoodbye() {
    console.log('goodbye');
}

$(window).on('load resize scroll', sayHello);
$(window).on('load resize scroll', sayGoodbye);
```

and when you want to stop saying hello just turn it [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/):

```
$(window).off('load resize scroll', sayHello);
```